# Wear your tzitzis out or in?

Tags: tzitzis, minhag

There seems to be some misunderstanding/machlokes (disagreement) on how you should wear your tzitzis - with the strings sticking out or tucked in. What's the proper way?

Answer (score 7):

An interesting thread about the subject can be found here : [Why do some people wear their tzitzis out for people to see, and others don't?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1797/wearing-your-tztzis-out)

Comment: Can you [edit] in a summary of the discussion?  We're looking for answers that are complete, not just links.  (I recognize that this answer is more than 2 years old and norms may have changed.)  Thanks.

Comment: This would be a much better answer if it included a summary.

Comment: In fact this question is a duplicate with the link I mentionned so it is why I've just post the link. Both offer good answers.

Comment: In that case, it should be a comment

Answer (score 5):

HUGE disagreement among the Poskim. Don't want to get too deep into it, but here is the summary (there are also different Pesakim in different cases- for all the details Yalkut Yosef is recommended):

- According to the Shulhan Aruch clearly (Orah Haim 8:11, 24:1) they Lechatehila should be revealed.
- Rav Ovadia Yosef (Yechawe Daat 2:1) holds the Tzitziot must be tucked in (see Halacha Berura ch.8, Yalkut Yosef ch. 8 and Or Lesion 2:2:2).
- Rav Yaakov Hilel writes (Gevurat HaAri pg. 137) that the Tzitziot must be revealed based on the Arizal (Shaar Hakawanot 7c and Olat Tamid 39a).
- According to the Hafes Haim they must be revealed and he is very harsh about this (Mishna Berura 8:26).

Comment: he says it is like a King gives you a Royal Medallion and you will not wear it I don't think he gives Allegories any where else to explain an Halacha I always found that intriguing

Comment: I find it interesting that you cite _SA_ on the one hand and _Rav Ovadya Yosef_ on the other. An unusual pair of _chol'kim_.

Comment: @msh210 that's why I get confused on Rav Ovadia's Piske Halachot sometimes.

Comment: @msh210 just today read in Rav Ovadia's Sefer "Livyat Hen" where is actually Matir something the Mehaber is Oser.

Comment: I think the Ben Ish Chai is also clear that the custom was to cover them.

Answer (score 4):

The Mishna Berura seems unclear. The bottem line is: if you will be wearing them sticking out of your pants (which many gedolim (great rabbis) did and still do) then you should do it in a way that it won't cause a [chillul hashem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chillul%5FHashem). If you live in a neighborhood which is full of frum jews, it shouldn't be an issue because even though there are gentiles there, they are used to the jews way of dressing.

Comment: It may not be an issue even in other areas. From personal experience, I have visited (in the course of my work) various corporate and government offices across the country, wearing tzitzis sticking out (and also a yarmulka and a full beard), and have always been treated most courteously. (Occasionally I've gotten questioned - respectfully, though - about what they are; but most people haven't even paid attention.)

Comment: The Mishnah Berurah is most definitely not ambiguous about it. He unabashedly condemns those who tuck them in, saying ועתידין הן ליתן את הדין על זה (and he goes on a further rant against those who use the excuse of being among gentiles)! (Full disclosure - Until a few minutes ago, I knew about the "Din" part of the M"B's statement, but I'd forgotten about the condemnation being extended against those who feel it's hard to do among non-Jews, and I'd relied upon that; I'm now rethinking that choice myself!)