# Dangling tzitzit

Tags: halacha, clothing, tzitzis

Do tzitzit need to dangle? Can one use some velcro to pin the strings down along the side of the beged so that they don't dangle down and get in the way of things?

Comment: Related: [Wearing your tzitzis out?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1797/wearing-your-tzitzis-out)

Comment: I'm wondering if the sugya of נוטפת על הקרן is relevant. They're supposed to hang _across the corner_. Would there be a problem with pinning them sideways and they're not hanging near the corner?

Answer (score 10):

**No,** they do **not** need to dangle. Many rabbis, including my Rosh Yeshiva, tuck their tzitzit under their belt to keep them neat and prevent them from ripping on nearby objects.  In addition, letting them dangle could be considered "undignified" and "*shlumpy*."  [Rabbi Menachem Posner of Chabad](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/758547/jewish/Do-I-need-to-let-my-tzitzit-hang-out.htm) recommends "tucking them under your belt and then into your pants pockets. This way, they are still visible, but stay neat and tidy."

In addition, one is permitted to tuck his tzitzit into his pants.  See [*Daily Halacha*](http://www.dailyhalacha.com/Display.asp?ClipDate=6/19/2011) and [this article on *Hirhurim*](http://hirhurim.blogspot.com/2005/11/tucking-in-tzitzis.html) for details.

Comment: In your examples they are still dangling off the beged. What if I attach them to the beged itself as in my quesiton?

Comment: Oh.  Interesting.  I'm not sure, but it makes sense that as long as they're not permanently sewn into that position, and are properly tied and knotted, it shouldn't be  a problem.  You should really ask your LOR.

Comment: @DoubleAA In your question, as far as I can tell, you are not attaching the actual Tzitzis to the begged. You are simply using velcro to keep the Tzitzis in place. Seems no worse than a belt.

Comment: @yydl true my intention was if one of the sides of the velcro was sewn to the back of the beged.

Comment: @DoubleAA Yep. So the velcro is sewn. The tzitzis are still technically their own entity.

Comment: Why is using velcro any different than fastening with a pin or tieing them to the beged?

Answer (score 5):

Of course there are plenty of opinions that allow you to tuck tzitzit into your pants, but it is not universally accepted. In *Az Nidberu*, HaRav Zilber *zt"l* wrote a very forceful tshuva saying you cannot tuck tzitzit in, and those who cite the Arizal misunderstood him!

I doubt that tzitzit *have to* dangle, but it seems to me they *should*. I vaguely recall a halacha regarding tangled tzitzit (the Gra is *machmir* on this) being problematic and the terminology of tzitzit tying -- the knotted section is called the *gid* and the rest is called the *anaf* -- seems to imply the tzitzit should dangle.

Comment: Can you cite the _Az Nidb'ru_?