# Can I tuck tzitzit into the fabric square corners?

Tags: halacha, tzitzis

These are Neatzit,

[image: Undershirt with very long slits up the sides and tzitzit-fringes attached at the four corners.]

a tzitzit undershirt. In dealing with a child who fidgets and therefore picks at the tzitzit, such that at the end of the day, they are entirely undone, can I tuck the tzitzit into the corner fabric squares? These squares are already partly open, to facilitate tucking the tzitzit in when going through the washing machine / dryer.

[image: The corner of a tzitzit-garment, with an extra square of fabric sewn onto it, and the tzitizt fringe attached.]

On the one hand, people do regularly tuck their tzitzit into their pants. On the other hand, when people do that, the garment stands by itself as a garment with hanging tzitzit. It is just that the tzitzit are not visible because of this other entity in the way. But here, with the tzitzit tucked in to the pocket squares, would they lose the status of tzitzit?

Comment: Dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11798/dangling-tzitzit

Comment: nice. baruch shekivanti. but i am not entirely convinced it is a dupe, because (a) with velcro, at least, the strings are visible outside the garment, such that they look like strings, and (b) all the answers there, including the accepted answer, conflated them with tucking into a belt, where this, in the question, explains why one might not conflate the two.

Comment: The strings are supposed to hang from the garment, "over the corner" (that is, in the manner of the lower of the 2 pictures above). Also, nice to see the GRA tying method used!

Comment: @snag by hanging from garment, you mean based on this? http://books.google.com/books?id=smV4tK-2BmAC&lpg=PA169&ots=WJR4eaOkbl&dq=are%20supposed%20to%20hang%20from%20the%20garment%2C%20%22over%20the%20corner%22&pg=PA169#v=onepage&q=are%20supposed%20to%20hang%20from%20the%20garment,%20%22over%20the%20corner%22&f=false is this then an answer, or just an aside as to which of the two pictures have the appropriate tying from the hole to the edge?

Answer (score 2):

Mishna Berurah in siman 8 siff 11 #25 quotes a Magen Avraham that whether or not you wear the beged on top or under your clothing, The strings should not be stuck into the corners. However, concerning people who go amongst the nonjews they fulfill their obligation with this. But when making the bracha, the strings should be exposed.

So, sticking them in the corners is not ideal, but works. How this plays out with chinuch is not addressed there, but now you have a more general question, does chinuch include a situation which is not ideal.

And in case you want to focus on chinuch for tzitzis specifically, see siman 17 siff 3.