# Does tzitzit have to hang? Can it be worn as a belt?

Tags: tzitzis

Can tzitzit be worn as a belt on the 4 belt loops? Meaning, can the tzitzis on the garment be looped through the belt loops, instead of just hanging?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/11798/759 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26161/759

Comment: Duplicate comment from there: I'm wondering if the sugya of נוטפת על הקרן is relevant. They're supposed to hang across the corner. Would there be a problem with pinning them sideways and they're not hanging near the corner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming the question is about wrapping the strings around the belt loops of the pants instead of leaving them hanging down. If I am wrong please correct me.

It would seem that Mishna Berura would permit this, if needed, as it would not be much different than tucking it into the "corner" or pockets of the pants.

> על בגדיו – ובכתבים איתא דטלית קטן תחת בגדיו. וכתב המגן אברהם, דעל כל פנים צריך שיהיו הציצית מבחוץ, ולא כאינך שתוחבין אותן בהכנפות. אך האנשים שהולכים בין העכו"ם יוצאין בזה. ומכל מקום בשעת הברכה יהיו מגולין [כדי הילוך] ארבע אמות.

> Over his clothing - And in כתבים it is brought that a טלית קטן [should be worn] under his clothing. And the Magen Avraham wrote, that in any case, the ציצית [strings] need to be outside, **and not like those that tuck them into the corners. However, the people that go/work amongst the non-Jews fulfill their obligation with that (ie. tucked in the corners)**. Nevertheless, at the time of [making] the blessing, they should be exposed [for the amount of time it takes to walk] four cubits.

> (כו) יראהו – כמה דכתיב: "וראיתם אותו וזכרתם" וגו'. ואותן האנשים המשימין הציצית בהמכנסים שלהם, לא די שמעלימין עיניהם ממאי דכתיב: "וראיתם אותו וזכרתם" וגו', עוד מבזין הן את מצוַת השם יתברך, ועתידין הן ליתן את הדין על זה. ומה שאומרין שהולכים בין הנוכרים, לזה היה די שישימו הציצית בתוך הכנף. ואילו היה להם איזה דורון ממלך בשר ודם שחקוק עליו שם המלך, כמה היו מתקשטין בו לפני האנשים תמיד; וקל וחומר בציצית, שמרמז על שם מלך מלכי המלכים הקדוש ברוך הוא, וכדלקמן בסימן כ"ד סעיף ה' – כמה מתכבד האדם הנושא שמו עליו! ואמרו חז"ל: "הזהיר במצוַת ציצית, זוכה ורואה פני השכינה". ומשמע מן הכתובים, דהיהודים שישארו לעת קץ יהיו מצויינים במצווה זו, כמה דכתיב: "ובאו עשרה אנשים מכל לשונות הגוים והחזיקו בכנף איש יהודי" וגו' (זכריה ח, כג). ואמרו חז"ל על זה (שבת לב ב): כל הזהיר במצות ציצית זוכה ומשמשין לו שני אלפים ושמונה מאות עבדים וכו'.

> See them - Like it is written "And you shall see it and remember" etc. And those people that put the ציצית into their pants, not only do they hide their eyes from (ie. ignore) what is written "And you shall see it and remember" etc... they also disgrace the mitzvah of השם יתברך, and they will have to make a reckoning over this. And this that they say that [they must do that because] they go amongst the non-Jews, **for that it would be enough to tuck the ציצית into the corner**. And if they had some gift from a king of flesh and blood which had the name of the king engraved in it... how much would they adorn themselves in front of other people constantly?; How much more so by ציצית, which is an allusion to the name of the King of all Kings, the Holy One Blessed Be He. And as is seen later in Siman 24, Se'if 5 - How honorable is the man who carries His Name on him! And חז"ל said: "One who is careful with the מצוה of ציצית, he merits to see the Face of the שכינה". And it is inferred from the verses, that they Jews that are remaining at the time [of redemption] will be found with this מצוה, as it is written: "And ten men from nations of every tongue will take hold of every Jew by a corner of his cloak" etc (Zechariah 9, 23). And חז"ל said on this (Shabbos 32, 2): Anyone who is careful in performing the מצוה of ציצית merits that two thousand eight hundred servants will serve him [in the World-to-Come]".