# Following minhag of tzitzit in vs. out

Tags: halacha, minhag, tzitzis

When I became frum (around 2 years ago) I started wearing tzitzit hanging out. My grandfather just told me that he remembers that when he was a kid, he tucked his tzitzit in. He remembers his father and grandfather (from Galitzia) doing the same. Should I switch my minhag? I prefer to wear them out, although if I am supposed to follow his minhag then I will switch.

Comment: CYLOR..........

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1797/759

Comment: @Sean, This looks like a personal question that you should address to your Rabbi. Please see http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/312/2. If you can reformulate this into a more general question for information that isn't a duplicate of http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1797/wearing-your-tzitzis-out , we could re-open it.

Comment: is this (now closed) question really about how to wear tzitzit, or is it about how to reconcile a potential (but only reported second hand) family minhag with a bal tshuva's new learning?